# How to replace string in SQL from index to index

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys can someone help me to write this?

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(55) = 'Name';
SELECT // SOME LOGIC


RESULT => 'NXXE'
```

I would like this logic to be generalized to replace every string except the first and last character.

Answer (score 3):

if `dynamic data masking` is not an answer you can use query below :

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'yourstring'
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(@str,1) + REPLICATE('x',LEN(@str) -2)+ RIGHT(@str,1))
```

Comment: @GiovanniGiampaolo you are welcome , to help community accept it as answer if it helped

Answer (score -1):

This is what you want

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(55) = 'Name';

declare @i int

Set @i = 0

while @i <= len(@STR )
begin
    select @i = @i + 1
if(@i>1 AND @i<len(@STR ))
    select @STR = STUFF(@STR , @i, 1, 'X')
END
SELECT @STR
```

Comment: Loops are bad in SQL - set-based is the way to go.